# Validate Email Availabilty on Update Form

Tags: sql-server, angular

I'm supposed to Validate email if they exist on database by showing error message.
My problem is when I will update on my form even the email that was not edited is affected by error message so I can't save even I don't have any changes on it.
Can you help me to validate email except the existing on update that has no changes?

```
@Email nvarchar(255),
@Email2 nvarchar(255)
    AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MembersTbl WHERE AuthorizedRep1Email = @Email OR AuthorizedRep2Email = @Email2)
            BEGIN
            SELECT 1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
            SELECT 0
            END
        END

    END
```

[image: Here's the email that has no changes but still affected on error.]

Comment: you control validation via the form controls, not in SQL. IE on click, if data has changed, then execute validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ignore the record you are editing when selecting records with the same email from database.

Something like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MembersTbl WHERE ID<>@CurrentID AND (AuthorizedRep1Email = @Email OR AuthorizedRep2Email = @Email2)
```

I don't know what database you use, but `ID<>@CurrentID` says `ID!=CURRENT_RECORD_ID`.